# sync php files on multiple web servers

Tags: php, webserver

I have 2 web servers and I need to edit files on both web servers every time i need to change something. What is the best way to sync the php files on multiple web servers?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Source code version control. I would suggest reading up on either subversion or git. In all honesty, you really shouldn't be programming without some sort of version control system.

Answer (score 0):

I've started to use Mercurial and this [FTP plugin](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/FTPExtension). Works pretty good. It supports multiple targets as well :)

Answer (score 0):

Version control is one good thing, if you use git you can add the 2 webservers as remotes and push them at your local brunch.

The other one you can use is the build on functionality in Netbeans, first you can map an smb or nfs path to your local filesystem. than in netbeans properties change run mode in remote and add the second server as php and choose "upload on save" so everytime you save the file you edit directly within server 1 and upload automaticly to server 2

Comment: Your option one requires shell access and git support on those web servers though? Second one sounds a bit of a pain, hehe.

Answer (score 0):

My friend, you got to use Lsync which synchronizes files between multiple web servers. Search google for Lsync and you sh